inoremap not working with Vim emulation and custom vimrc in Visual Studio Code
I’m using the Vim extension in Visual Studio Code.
I have set up a vimrc path to use my custom vim commands. All of them work (from what I see) except this one to remap Escape:
:inoremap jj <Esc>

which always prints "jj" instead of quitting insert mode. Any idea why? Is this extension limited to keybindings in normal mode and not insert mode?

VSCodeVim is not vim, it's a bad emulation. Perhaps something was not implemented. In a real vim the mapping works, I just tested.

@phd yes I know I also use Vim. I’m just using VSC for different reasons at the moment and wondering if this is a bug or not.

Still not sure if this is a bug or what, but as a workaround, setting this remap directly in settings.json works:
"vim.insertModeKeyBindings": [
        {
            "before": ["j", "j"],
            "after": ["<Esc>"]
        }
    ]

